# Server's socket blocking if no newline detected but client's socket not

Tags: c#, sockets

While setting up a TCP server-client connection, I realized that the server receive function hangs if the client does not send an '\n', but the client does not block if the sever doesn't. I tried searching for an explanation without finding a proper answer, so I came here to ask for your help.

I am using the same function to exchange data for both server and client, but I don't know why it works for one and doesn't for the other...

Here is my function in C#:

```
public bool sendToClient(int i, string msg)
{
    try
    {                    
        (clientSockets.ElementAt(i)).mSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private string getMessageFromConnection(Socket s)
{
    byte[] buff;
    string msg = "";
    int k;
    do
    {
        buff = new byte[100];

        k = s.Receive(buff, 100, SocketFlags.None);

        msg += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 0, k);

    } while (k >= 100);

    return msg;
}
```

The sockets are simple SOCK_STREAM ones, and the clientSockets is a list containing Client objects containing each client info including their socket.

I understand that one solution would be to detect a particular character to end the message, but I would like to know the reason behind it because I also had this issue using C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I also had this issue using C." -- is not a good enough reason for tagging ``C`` language. You need to show your C code for justifying the tag.

Comment: The socket level operations like ``read`` or ``recv`` are not concerned about whether a new line is received or not for returning back. It just returns when the configured amount of data is available (generally 1 byte and this discussion is for blocking IO).

Comment: @MohithReddy oh okay I am new to posting question thank you. So you think that I should read byte by byte to avoid the problem ?

Comment: That depends upon what are you trying to achieve. How do you want the server and client to behave ?

Comment: @MohithReddy I am trying to build a sort of chat room for a university project. So I am trying to exchange data like username and server response like "OK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop continues only as long as you're reading exactly 100 bytes, and it seems that you intend to use that to detect the end of a message.

This will fail if the message is exactly 100 or any multitude of 100 bytes (in which case it will append a subsequent message to it).

But even worse - there is no guarantee that the socket will return 100 bytes, even if there is data still on its way. `Receive` does not wait until the underlying buffer has reached 100 bytes, it will return whatever it has available at that point.

You're going to have to either include a header that indicates the message length, or have a terminator character that indicates the end of the message.

Comment: Ohh I didn't realize the wrong condition, thanks! I will try to fix it.